# OpenCV Android app crash when using drawContour

Tags: java, android, opencv

I'm new to android and my application crashes after some time when I use drawcontour. The application has to look for the largest contour and compute its bounding box. Here is a sample of my code:

```
public Mat onCameraFrame(CvCameraViewFrame inputFrame) {
    img_rgb = inputFrame.rgba();

    Imgproc.blur(img_rgb, blur, new Size(25,25));
    Imgproc.cvtColor(blur, img_gray, Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
    Imgproc.threshold(img_gray, thres1, 0, 255, Imgproc.THRESH_OTSU);
    Imgproc.erode(thres1, erode1, new Mat(), new Point(-1,-1), 3);
    Imgproc.dilate(erode1, dilate1, new Mat(), new Point(-1,-1), 2);
    Imgproc.erode(dilate1, erode2, new Mat(), new Point(-1,-1), 3);
    Imgproc.dilate(erode2, dilate2, new Mat(), new Point(-1,-1), 2);
    Imgproc.adaptiveThreshold(dilate2, thres2, 128,Imgproc.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_MEAN_C, Imgproc.THRESH_BINARY_INV,7, 1);

    contours = new ArrayList<MatOfPoint>();
    Imgproc.findContours(thres2, contours, hierarchy, Imgproc.RETR_TREE, Imgproc.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE, new Point(0, 0));


    hierarchy.release();

    //Imgproc.drawContours(img_rgb, contours, -1, new Scalar(Math.random()*255, Math.random()*255, Math.random()*255));//, 2, 8, hierarchy, 0, new Point());

    for(int i = 0;i<contours.size();i++){
        double area = Imgproc.contourArea(contours.get(i));

        if(area > largest_area){
            largest_area = area;
            largest_contour_index = i;
            bounding_rect = Imgproc.boundingRect(contours.get(i));
        }
    }

    Imgproc.drawContours(img_rgb,contours,largest_contour_index, new Scalar(0,255,0),2);



    return img_rgb;
}
```

Comment: What errors are you getting when the app crashes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You never reset `largest_area` and `largest_contour_index`, so it may happen that `largest_contour_index` refers to an invalid index.

You only need to reset these values at each loop, and draw the contour only if the index is valid (i.e. if you find at least one contour). Depending on your further processing, you may want also to reset `bounding_rect`. You can move the `boundingRect` call out of the for loop, so you avoid useless computation.

Code:

```
// Reset values at each iteration
largest_area = 0;
largest_contour_index = -1;

for(int i = 0;i<contours.size();i++){
    double area = Imgproc.contourArea(contours.get(i));

    if(area > largest_area){
        largest_area = area;
        largest_contour_index = i;          
    }
}

// Draw only if index is valid
if(largest_contour_index >= 0) {
     bounding_rect = Imgproc.boundingRect(contours.get(largest_contour_index));
     Imgproc.drawContours(img_rgb,contours,largest_contour_index, new Scalar(0,255,0),2);
}
```

Comment: thank, it work. i actually put those in the main class. put did not think i should put it again

Comment: You are not re-declaring them. You just need to reset their value at each iteration. After all, they don't need to be class members at all.